# How to edit a GitLab managed Terraform state file?

Tags: terraform, gitlab, amazon-rds

I seem to have encountered a long-standing Terraform issue, where I have attempted to create an AWS RDS Cluster without having specified `skip_final_snapshot = true`,
however any attempt to extricate myself from this situation (e.g. to try to set `skip_final_snapshot = true`, or to set a `final_snapshot_identifier`) all fail with the same error:

```
aws_rds_cluster.example_db_cluster: Destroying... [id=example-default-cluster]

Error: RDS Cluster final_snapshot_identifier is required when skip_final_snapshot is false
```

This issue is documented in a [GitHub issue from 2016](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/5417#issuecomment-223733146) (albeit related to `terraform destroy`, but it looks like the same underlying cause), along with a potential workaround, which is:

> Looks like `terraform destroy` looks for the `skip_final_snapshot` option in the state file. After I manually added `"skip_final_snapshot": "true"` to the state file, terraform destroy worked. However I don't like messing with the state file by hand.

However, my Terraform state file is managed by the GitLab http backend (using the SaaS version of GitLab). GitLab offers the means to remove the state file, or to download the init, but no obvious means of editing the managed state file.

I would appreciate either a workaround to the existing problem of getting out of this state where I can't change the `final_snapshot` parameters because of the existing configuration error, or some help with how to manually override that parameter in the GitLab managed state file.